# Does minimizing the browser allow selenium to work faster?

Tags: selenium

I'm new to using selenium, and I am automating a task where selenium will continuously refresh the best buy page and tell me if an item has changed to "in stock". I will then receive an email alert if that is the case. I am accomplishing that by using, in part:

```
while True:
   driver.refresh()
   print(datetime.now())
   ...
```

I'm then having selenium report out the time, as seen above. When the browser is open, the average time it takes to report the next time is around 3 seconds. However, when I minimize the window, that reduces to ~1.5 seconds.

Does minimizing the browser make driver.refresh() occur faster, and should I keep the browser minimized so that the stock-checker works faster?

Comment: you can try headless mode,  or if you want to make the automation fast, can try some other modules not using web driver, such as playwright(using Chrom devtool protocol), clicknium(using native message host)

Comment: Whenever I try headless mode, nothing happens. I have the program print a statement every time it pings the website, but when the program is run in headless mode, the script kind of just sits there and does nothing. No errors and the script doesn't stop, but also no indication anything is happening. Not sure what to make of that.